How to use only the move constructor and the move assignment operator
Please tell me how I can correct this piece of code so that the cookie_name_t class does not use a copy constructor and an assignment constructor.
When I do the following:
cookie_name(cookie_name const &) = delete;            
cookie_name &operator=(cookie_name const &) = delete; 

in the cookie_name_t class, the code not compiling.
Everything breaks down in the insert_or_update function.
class cookie_name final
{
public:
    using value_type = std::string;

    cookie_name() = delete;

    // Copy constructor can throw, so no noexcept here
    cookie_name(value_type const &value) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<value_type>) : value_{value} {};

    // Move constructor is noexcept
    cookie_name(value_type &&value) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<value_type>) : value_{std::move(value)} {};

    cookie_name(cookie_name const &) = default;            
    cookie_name &operator=(cookie_name const &) = default; 

    // Default move constructor and move assignment are noexcept
    cookie_name(cookie_name &&) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<value_type>) = default;         // for NRVO
    cookie_name &operator=(cookie_name &&) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<value_type>) = default; // for NRVO

    value_type operator()() const noexcept { return value_; } // for return value

    // Comparison operators are noexcept
    bool operator==(cookie_name const &rhs) const noexcept { return this->value_ == rhs.value_; }
    bool operator!=(cookie_name const &rhs) const noexcept { return !(this->value_ == rhs.value_); }

private:
    value_type value_;
};
using cookie_name_t = cookie_name;
using cookie_value_t = cookie_value;

class cookies final
{
public:
    using cookie_t = std::tuple<cookie_name_t, cookie_value_t, cookie_options_t>;

private:
    using raw_cookie_t = std::vector<cookie_t>;

public:
    cookies() = default;

    void cookie(cookie_name_t const &cookie, cookie_value_t const &value) { insert_or_update(std::make_tuple(cookie(), value(), std::string{})); }
    auto write_cookies() const;

private:
    void insert_or_update(cookie_t &&cookie);

private:
    raw_cookie_t cookies_;
};
void cookies::insert_or_update(cookie_t &&cookie)
{
    auto value{std::find_if(cookies_.begin(), cookies_.end(), [&cookie](auto &iter)
                            { return get<0>(iter)() == get<0>(cookie)(); })};
    if (value == cookies_.end())
        cookies_.emplace_back(cookie);
    else
        *value = std::move(cookie);
}


cookies_.emplace_back(std::move(cookie)); should fix the error, I suspect.

You just need to use std::move. See What is std::move and when it should be used
